# Is there any tool or method to find out the infinite loop within magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2

I have magento site having 145 extension installed. There are different custom and 3rd party plugins.

The problem is any event trigger on some random condition and make server down.

any tool that scan php or magento code for looping query and infinite loop.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you install/enable the [XDebug PHP extension](https://xdebug.org/) it will throw an error when a configured maximum nesting level is reached (default: 100). Since you probably have infinite recursion and not an infinite loop, PHP will stop before your server gets down. Then you can inspect the error logs to find out where it happened.

Note that in Magento 2 or even in M1 with many extensions the default treshold of 100 can be reached without a case of infinite recursion. So it's recommended to set the value to 200. See also: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/trouble/tshoot_install-issues.html#known-devbeta-xdebug